# What image lies behind the expression "Take a bow"?

Tags: idioms, expressions

I heard this expression in the Rihanna's eponymic song.

I understand the general meaning, but where does it come from? What is the image behind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a show (such a play, or musical performance) it is common for the artists to "take a bow" which gives the audience the opportunity to show their appreciation through applause:

[image: Artists taking a bow at the end of a performance]

In this case, "take a bow" is being used sarcastically by Rihanna because she is implying that the subject of the song is "putting on a performance" i.e. being insincere, and Rihanna is implying that he should stop acting and should "take a bow" after his "performance".